# Link structure in Top Menu from amp sites

Tags: amp-html

hello and greetings from germany.

i have created a amp side for my domain https://www.fruchthof24.de. The Link to my amp Site is https://www.fruchthof24.de/amp/
And another site with the amp-site.
in this amp-sites i have a menue on top, it is correct to link to amp-sites or to the original sites?

Answer (score 1):

you are correctly linking the amp version and the canonical version, but you are missing the right metadata in your amp file. Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories#markup_specification.

Moreover, your question is tagged "amp" but it should be tagged "amp-html".

Hope this helps.

Comment: down vote
accept
 

thank you.

but this site in my question is the mainpage from my domain. it is not a newsarticle, or must be set in all amp sites the meta data for newsarticle? exist another meta data for commerce and shopping sites? i would create amp sites for my blog news article and with this metadata https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories#markup_specification.

greetings

Comment: At the moment, "The Top Stories carousel requires schema.org markup for one of the following types: Article, NewsArticle, BlogPosting, or VideoObject." (taken from https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories#markup_specification). The best strategy is creating AMP pages only for leaf articles of the types above so that they will appear in the carousel. You can create an AMP version for the mainpage, but it will not appear in the carousel. Other type of articles are not supported at the moment.